# matplotlibで矢印の太さを変えたい

Tags: python, matplotlib

python3.6を使っています。matplotlibを使って描いた矢印の太さを大きくしたいです。次は実際に書いてみたコードです。

```
X=0
Y=0
U=1
V=2
plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V,linewidths=10,angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1)
plt.xlim([-1,2])
plt.ylim(-1,2)
```

これによって、次のようなグラフが描写されます。

[image: 画像]

ここで、linewidthsの値を変えれば太さが変わるような気がしましたが、変わりませんでした。linewidthでもlwにしてみてもダメでした。しかし、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701952/change-size-of-arrows-using-matplotlib-quiver
このページのコードでは太さが変わっています。このようなことが可能なのでしょうか？私のPCではこのページのコードを打ってみても、ベクトルの太さは変化しませんでした。私のPCの環境はWindows10の64bitで、matplotlibのバージョンは2.1.2です。

Comment: `import matplotlib` の後 `print(matplotlib.__version__)` をした結果も追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: 「そんなことはありませんでした」というのは、何も変わらなかったということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: はい、何も変化しませんでした。matplotlibのバージョンは2.1.2です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linewidth` ではなく、`width` を使用してください。以下はこの引数の[ドキュメント](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html)からの引用です。

> **width** : scalar, optional
>   Shaft width in arrow units; default depends on choice of units, above, and number of vectors; a typical starting value is about 0.005 times the width of the plot.

`linewidth` は矢印の枠線と矢印自体の面との色を別々にしたいときに有効となるオプションであり、今回の用途には向いていません……と、matplotlib のメンテナーの方が[こちらのコメント](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8630#issuecomment-301885921)でおっしゃっていました。

Comment: 非常に素早い回答ありがとうございます！私なりに調べてみたつもりだったのですが、ドキュメントを見ればよかったのですね。